# spring-mvc : merge pdf files and display them in web browser

Tags: spring-mvc, pdfbox

I need to merge multiple pdf files into one pdf and display it in my web browser.
I know how to display one file :

```
File file = new File(activite.getLienUploadUn());
FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);

byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

int bytesRead;
while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1)
{
     baos.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
}


response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","inline; filename=\""+file.getName()+"\"");
response.setContentType("application/pdf");
ServletOutputStream outputStream = response.getOutputStream();
baos.writeTo(outputStream);
outputStream.flush();
```

I think I am going to use PdfBox and its PDFMergerUtility class to merge files :

```
PDFMergerUtility mergePdf = new PDFMergerUtility();
mergePdf.addSource(file);
mergePdf.mergeDocuments(MemoryUsageSetting.setupMainMemoryOnly());
```

But from there how can I convert the merged document into a byteArrayOutputStream?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `PDFMergerUtility.setDestinationStream(OutputStream destStream)` to pass an output stream ([javadoc](https://pdfbox.apache.org/docs/2.0.3/javadocs/org/apache/pdfbox/multipdf/PDFMergerUtility.html#setDestinationStream(java.io.OutputStream))).